# How to Install Lampp on Ubuntu Text user interface (TUI)?

Tags: php, ubuntu, oci8, lampp

download https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
xampp-linux-installer.run

i have ubuntu os but without GUI, and i don't have acces directly.
i'm using putty, does anyone know how to install it ?

cause when we run installer.run usualy  will show popup xampp installer  (GUI) but when we use TUI or remote via putty popup does not show.

i'm stuck in it.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the LAMP Stack as follows (Please note that some steps will have on-screen instructions you should read and follow):

NOTE: You can use the following command to see which packages are actually available before installing

`apt-cache search keyword`

For example `apt-cache search php`

STEPS

1.`sudo apt-get install apache2`

2. `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
3. `sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0`
4. Restart the server using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart`
5. Check Apache by visiting this url: `http://localhost/`
6. Check your PHP by running a PHP file from /var/www/html/ or go interactive.
   `php -a`
   `echo "Hello, World";`

More [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu).

Comment: Thank's for your answer. bu i want to install lampp. now apache stand alone.
i'm try again with my team and done.

Comment: sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ (this will install LAMP with all dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Install Lampp on Putty or in OS TUI (text user interface) can work normally.
not in pop up by in text view but overall running well.
sorry for my dumb question.